# Sending multiple scheduled HTTP request in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, automated-tests, load-testing

I have a csv input file like this:

```
timestamp, request url
e.g: 20/Sep/2018:00:00:00, /posts/1
```

This file contains about 1.5 million likes this. Is it possible to make a load test in JMeter where I can schedule all of these requests by his timestamp, or set a delay between them, while iterate through requests. Furthermore, reuse a thread, if a thread is finished then get another request and send it ... repetaing it until all tasks are done.
Actually I can read the path from csv, but can't use the timestamps, and reuse threads.

If JMeter is not suitable for this kind of task, could you recommend some other tool that can do this kind of work?

Answer (score 1):

1. Take a look at [Access Log Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Access_Log_Sampler) - it is designed to replay production traffic using web/application server [access logs](https://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/access-log)

   Given your input file format is in line with what JMeter expects you should be able to replay the requests using single sampler. Check out [Access log sampler Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_accesslog_sampler_step_by_step.html) guide for more details.
2. If you will not be able to "feed" your file to JMeter's Access Log Sampler you can use some Groovy scripting in order to

   - Configure JMeter's HTTP Request sampler URL via [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor)
   - Define "sleep time" using [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor)

   Check out [Stop Making Assumptions! Learn How to Replay Your Production Traffic With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/stop-making-assumptions-learn-how-replay-your-production-traffic-jmeter) article for example configuration implementation
3. With regards to re-using threads - this is something JMeter does by default given you supply >1 Loop in [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

   [image]

   in the above setup a single thread will execute the HTTP Request sampler 1000 times.

Comment: Thanks for your help! But I need some more help with scheduling. 
I write this JSR223 Timer:
`def startTime = (Long)1540332022;

if(vars.get("line") == "0"){
 return 0; 
} else {
 def currentTime = Long.parseLong(vars.get("timestamp"));
 def delay = (currentTime - startTime);
 delay *= 1000;
 log.info(" " + delay);
 //sleep(delay);
 return delay;
}`

But as you can see it doesn't start the thread as it should [link](http://imgur.com/doLoxwAl.png) 

A difference between the first one and the last one should be only 15s.